# "Unsupported Context on :enter " when reitit interceptors are updated to async

Tags: clojure, reitit

I'm working on reitit http application which uses interceptors.

Below is my code

```
(ns ic.reitit-interceptor-multithreading)

(require '[reitit.ring :as ring])
(require '[reitit.http :as http])
(require '[reitit.interceptor.sieppari :as sieppari])
(require '[clojure.core.async :refer [go]])
(defn interceptor [number]
  {:enter (fn [ctx]
            (go
              (println "in enter interceptor" number (.getName (Thread/currentThread)))
              (update-in ctx [:request :number] (fnil + 0) number)))})

(def app
  (http/ring-handler
   (http/router
    ["/api"
     {:interceptors [(interceptor 1)]}

     ["/number"
        {:interceptors [(interceptor 10)]
         :get {:interceptors [(interceptor 100)]
               :handler (fn [req]
                          (println "in handler")
                          {:status 200
                           :body (select-keys req [:number])})}}]])

   ;; the default handler
   (ring/create-default-handler)

   ;; executor
   {:executor sieppari/executor}))
```

When I'm executing the code in repl I get error -

```
(require '[ic.reitit-interceptor-multithreading :refer :all])
(app {:request-method :get, :uri "/api/number"})
```

The error I get is -

> Loading src/ic/reitit_interceptor_multithreading.clj... done
> (app {:request-method :get, :uri "/api/number"})
> Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at sieppari.core/-invalid-context-type! (core.cljc:34).
> Unsupported Context on :enter - clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@4abe39b8
> in enter interceptor 1 async-dispatch-3

When I remove `go` macro from interceptor enter function then it is working fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `[sieppari.async.core-async :as ca]` into `ns` definition:

```
(ns ic.reitit-interceptor-multithreading
  (:require
    [reitit.ring :as ring]
    [reitit.http :as http]
    [reitit.interceptor.sieppari :as sieppari]
    [clojure.core.async :refer [go]]
    [sieppari.async.core-async :as ca])
  (:gen-class))
```

Then call `(app {:request-method :get, :uri "/api/number"})` again.

Maybe there is an easier way, so here is full explanation:

Look into a stack trace and see, which functions are called:

- [`-invalid-context-type!`](https://github.com/metosin/sieppari/blob/bfc76d46d7fa01d85178e5454a4274c0461fb7c4/src/sieppari/core.cljc#LL32)
- [`enter`](https://github.com/metosin/sieppari/blob/bfc76d46d7fa01d85178e5454a4274c0461fb7c4/src/sieppari/core.cljc#LL49)

Interceptor has to return context map (`c/context?`) or async channel (`a/async?`). `go` should return the async channel, so you will look for `async?` definition. `async?` is a method of [`AsyncContext` protocol](https://github.com/metosin/sieppari/blob/bfc76d46d7fa01d85178e5454a4274c0461fb7c4/src/sieppari/async.cljc) and [returns `false`](https://github.com/metosin/sieppari/blob/bfc76d46d7fa01d85178e5454a4274c0461fb7c4/src/sieppari/async.cljc#L23) for any object. [sieppari/async/core_async.cljc](https://github.com/metosin/sieppari/blob/bfc76d46d7fa01d85178e5454a4274c0461fb7c4/src/sieppari/async/core_async.cljc) extends this protocol to async channels, which should return `true`.